# mysql multi filter into 1 view

Tags: mysql

i have 2 tables as bellow

> table1 - the entry data is made by production planner .(main order data)

| orderid | production_date | material | userid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-05-07 | leather | user1 |
| 325 | 2021-05-07 | leather | user2 |
| 326 | 2021-05-08 | leather | user3 |
| 327 | 2021-05-08 | fabric | user4 |

> table2 the entry data is by worker entry as out (finish task)

| orderid | production_date | production_type | userid | timestamp | prouction_status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-05-07 | leather | user1 | 2021-05-07 | in |
| 325 | 2021-05-08 | leather | user2 | 2021-05-07 | out |
| 326 | 2021-05-08 | leather | user3 | 2021-05-07 | out |

i want to make a single table with multi filters and calcs
as bellow

number 1

```
select table1.production_date  , 
          count(*) as total_task1 from table1
```

filter total orders

number 2

```
select table1.production_date  , 
      count(*) as total_task  from table1
where table1.production_type = "leather"
```

total order filtered by  "leather"

number 3

```
select table2.production_date  , 
          count(*) as total_out  from table1
    where table2.production_type = "leather"
```

total task filter by leather (total in and total out)

at the end i want to combine those examples to get table  or view as below bellow

| production_date | total_order | total_leather_order | total_in | total_out | balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-08 | 4 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 1 |

balance will be total_leather_out- total_order = balance (not processed yet)

and group by production_date  = CURDATE()

is it possible ?any one can give me a hint . thank u

Comment: Your queries are malformed. They can only run in MySQL 5.7.5 or older and will return unpredictable results.

Comment: I see 4 total orders, and 3 leather orders, but you expect 3 and 2 instead. Why?

Comment: my bad  ,  i edit it  now  , so any hint guys  ? for second table  have only 3 " reason  task only run 3 still on going "

Comment: In each case, please identify your primary key

Comment: primary key should be orderid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
select
  o.*, 
  e.*,
  o.total_order - o.total_leather_order as balance
from (
  select
    count(*) as total_order,
    sum(case when material = 'leather' then 1 else 0 end) as total_leather_order
  from table1
) o
cross join (
  select
    sum(case when production_status = 'in' then 1 else 0 end) as total_in,
    sum(case when production_status = 'out' then 1 else 0 end) as total_out,
  from table2
) e
```

**Note**: I didn't quite understand the logic to compute the balance. Nevertheless, the subtotals are now there, so you can compute it as needed.

Comment: The Impaler thank u very much , that help a lot

Comment: can u give me a push pls if i want to group by production date  ? i couldnt get it to work i means i get it to work for 1 table only if i use for 2 table data is wrong

Comment: @AliIm Your expected result does not include grouping by date. Can you add the new expected result?

Comment: result expexted as group by product_id = CURDATE() ( i missed up  i got no clue i knew date 08 as example i gave is count  date is 2  )